# How to dynamically add ng-repeat to an element inside an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to add 'ng-repeat="n in counter"' to the 'form' tag inside my directive. How do I do this?
I tried accessing the element via compile but tElement.find('form') does not work.

See : http://jsfiddle.net/fea40v2c/1/

I tried all these variations:

```
        console.log(tElement.find('form')); // fails
        console.log(tElement[0].querySelector('form')); // null
        console.log(document.querySelector('form')); // fails
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the add button to be defined by the directive's user? Because if you don't you can do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fea40v2c/3/).

```
<script id="repeatableForm.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="add()">
    <div ng-repeat="c in counter">
        <div ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**Update**

After a little work I got something that allows the user to provide their own markup for the add button. It a bit more complicated and involves a nested directive. A few points that are good to know:

- The `repeatableForm` directive has no isolated scope. It modifies the host scope by adding/overwriting the `repeatableForm` property. This means multiple such directives cannot execute in the same host scope.
- The `repeatableForm` publishes its controller in its host scope as the `repeatableForm` property. This is better than publishing the controller's methods directly in the scope because it namespaces those methods and leaves the host scope cleaner.

The view

```
<repeatable-form>
    <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="repeatableForm.add()"/>
    <form action="">
        First Name: <input name="fname" type="text" />
        Last Name: <input name="lname" type="text" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Steak"/> Steak
        <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Egg"/> Egg
        <input type="button" value="remove" ng-click="repeatableForm.remove($index)" />
    </form>
</repeatable-form>
```

The directives

```
app.directive('repeatableForm', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl:'repeatableForm.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        controller: function () {
            var repeatableForm = this
            repeatableForm.add = function () {
                repeatableForm.forms.push(repeatableForm.forms.length + 1);
            };
            repeatableForm.remove = function (index) {
                repeatableForm.forms.splice(index, 1);                 
            };
            repeatableForm.forms = [1, 2, 3];
        },
        controllerAs: 'repeatableForm',
    };
});

app.directive('form', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'repeatedForm.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
    };
})
```

The templates

```
<script id="repeatableForm.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div ng-transclude></div>
</script>
<script id="repeatedForm.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div ng-repeat="form in repeatableForm.forms"><div ng-transclude></div></div>
</script>
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fea40v2c/13/).

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could upvote you twice! The very slight problem with this is that it is all in a single form element, but that was a quick fix: http://jsfiddle.net/h0a23ubf/2/. Interestingly I do not know why this isn't working (changed the repeatedform directive to be an attribute): http://jsfiddle.net/h0a23ubf/4/. Replace false removes the original form element, the input should be transcluded into the form which should repeat.

Comment: It doesn't work because the directive's template has to have only one root element *once rendered*. So you can't put a `ng-repeat` on the root element. Fortunately, all you have to do is wrap everything into a `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/h0a23ubf/5/.